# How to update Azure Search Index every seconds?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cognitive-search

I have a small azure search index (28K doc / 50 Mb) with around 600 updates a day from one Azure SQL server data source and need to have an efficient search solution near "real time" (meaning that each time a row is created or updated in the DB I would like to have the updates in my search results within one or 2 seconds max). I also would like to avoid modifying all our code to push the data to the index each time we update our DB.

Is there a way to have some automation within Azure to update the index each time the Azure SQL server DB is updated ... WITHOUT pushing the data?

- from a logic app checking every second or 2 new or updated entries :

  - and running the indexer when needed with a custom connector?
  - OR pushing new row to the index with a custom connector?
- from a view with a timestamp column (but it seems that indexer autorun minimum delay is 5 minutes)?
- from a table with SQL Integrated Change Tracking Policy (same ... 5 minutes seems to be the minimum time range update)?

Is there another way (without pushing data)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run an indexer on-demand using the [Run Indexer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/run-indexer). This can work well for occasional updates. However, if you're constantly adding new rows to the SQL table, you may want to consider batching to improve indexing performance.

Correct, 5 minutes is currently the minimal supported schedule interval.